# YII framework, is SSH required to run protected/yiic.php migrate

Tags: php, yii, ssh, migrate

We have a company doing several websites for us using the YII framework. The developers tell us that in order to run protected/yiic.php migrate that they **must** have SSH access to our server.

We are reluctant to provide SSH as there are many clients on our server. Is SSH really required as they say or can this migration script run via other means via the web browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can write php-script, that will execute migrates, use CConsoleCommand for base, but it is not simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way run the migration only SSH, but approach proposed by Alex also nice.